# Measuring Functional Dispersion - Species labels in 'd' and 'a' need to be identical and ordered alphabetically (or simply in the same order)

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio, pacman

I am using someone's code to calculate functional dispersion of bird species for sites across the UK

Using the FD package

```
fd_mi <- fdisp(gd_mi, ts_mi$eco_mi)
```

Above is the line of code I am using

This is the error message I get: "Species labels in 'd' and 'a' need to be identical and ordered alphabetically (or simply in the same order)".

I guess this means that my species names in two datasets that I joined do not match, however I have checked this in excel and it appears they do. Can anyone help?

Comment: You'll have to give us a few more details. Are `gd_mi` and `ts_mi$eco_mi` both matrices? Looks like the function needs the species labels to be the same and in the same order. If they are the same, it might be a case of reordering the columns in one of the matrices. Providing some sample data might help. If your matrices are small enough, you could give us the output from `dput(gd_mi)` and `dput(ts_mi$eco_mi)`.

Comment: Sorry! yes, they are both matrices, do you know how I would make sure the species labels are in the same order in the columns? My matrices are quite large as it is all occurrence of bird species across all 10km2 sites in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the function wants your data to look like:

```
> dummy.dist
          sp1       sp2       sp3       sp4       sp5       sp6       sp7
sp2 0.2181884                                                            
sp3 0.5240052 0.6678082                                                  
sp4 0.6737443 0.5610028 0.8225701                                        
sp5 0.5291113 0.8145699 0.4862253 0.4843264                              
sp6 0.6100161 0.5932587 0.2784736 0.7073925 0.6067323                    
sp7 0.4484235 0.6863374 0.4848663 0.5575126 0.3023416 0.6187844          
sp8 0.4072834 0.2039443 0.5958904 0.2390962 0.5585525 0.4470207 0.7030186

> dummy$abun
      sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4 sp5 sp6 sp7 sp8
com1    1   1   0   0   4   2   0   0
com2    0   0   0   2   1   0   0   5
com3    2   0   0   0   0   1   0   3
com4    1   0   7   0   0   0   0   0
com5    0   0   2   3   3   0   0   0
com6    0   3   0   0   5   6   1   6
com7    3   5   0   3   0   0   0   0
com8    0   0   0   0   6   2   1   2
com9    4   1   1   3   0   0   2   0
com10   0   4   1   0   0   0   6   1

# If we rearrange the columns in the abundance matrix...
shuffled <- dummy$abun[, sample(1:ncol(dummy$abun))]

> shuffled
      sp4 sp8 sp3 sp2 sp1 sp6 sp5 sp7
com1    0   0   0   1   1   2   4   0
com2    2   5   0   0   0   0   1   0
com3    0   3   0   0   2   1   0   0
com4    0   0   7   0   1   0   0   0
com5    3   0   2   0   0   0   3   0
com6    0   6   0   3   0   6   5   1
com7    3   0   0   5   3   0   0   0
com8    0   2   0   0   0   2   6   1
com9    3   0   1   1   4   0   0   2
com10   0   1   1   4   0   0   0   6


#...and run the function...
ex1 <- fdisp(dummy.dist, shuffled)

# ...we get this error:
# Species labels in 'd' and 'a' need to be identical and ordered alphabetically
#  (or simply in the same order).

# Assuming the number and names of species are the same,
#  we can put them in the same order as the dist matrix:
shuffled[, attr(dummy.dist, 'Labels')]

# So if your issue is just the order, you might be able to solve it with:
fd_mi <- fdisp(gd_mi, ts_mi$eco_mi[, attr(gd_mi, 'Labels')])
```

If that doesn't help, here's how you can start troubleshooting your issue:

```
# These two things should be:
class(gd_mi) # should be 'dist'
class(ts_mi$eco_mi) # should be 'matrix'

# These two numbers should be the same:
attr(gd_mi, 'Size')
ncol(ts_mi$eco_mi)

# If they're not the same, this might show you which species names in gd_mi are not in ts_mi$eco_mi:
setdiff(attr(gd_mi, 'Labels'), colnames(ts_mi$eco_mi))

# If that still doesn't point to the issue, show us the output from:
str(gd_mi)
str(ts_mi$eco_mi)
```

**Disclaimer**: I don't have any experience with the `FD` package, but I always try to help biologists on here.

Comment: thank you SO much! solved it using your code, the problem was simply a non capital letter in one of the species names. Appreciate your help so much!